# cell.textLabel.text not displaying text on my InboxViewController

Tags: ios7, parse-platform

I have the following code which is supposed to display messages on my inboxViewController which is a `UITableViewController`, but for some reason the messages don't show up. I even tried to hard code it like `[cell.textLabel.text=@"Yes"]` but still nothing happened. Here is my codeL

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    PFObject *message=[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=[message objectForKey:@"senderName"];
    NSLog(@"senderName: %@", [message objectForKey:@"senderName"]);
    return cell;
}
```

also i am using parse.com which is where i store all my users `data.self.messages` contains all the user's messages. Its a PFObject which has a key called `senderName` which contains the sender's name.So i am trying to display the sender's name on my inboxViewController.

Comment: Have you verified that the `cell.textLabel.textColor` is set to a color that _isn't_ the same as the `cell.contentView.backgroundColor`?

Comment: hmmmm, how do i check that

Comment: i just added cell.textlabel.textColor=[uicolor redcolor]; no text was still displayed

Comment: Your casing is incorrect – use `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]` instead.

Comment: yes thats exactly what i did, i was just lazy to write it like that here

Comment: If other people are taking the time to answer your question, you may want to take the time to explain yourself correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i founf the error, i forgot to reload my data in the viewWillAppear method.